# Reactive form validation issue

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-reactive-forms

***ngIf is not working properly**

My form has invalid fields; the primary if condition is working perfectly but when I show a specific error message this is not working properly. ( Example :  `*ngIf="PopupForm.get('startdate').errors?.required`)

```
<div *ngIf="PopupForm.get('startdate').errors && submitted">
   <div class="form-text error" *ngIf="PopupForm.get('startdate').errors?.required">Start date is required</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Should be work. Use in your .html `<pre>{{PopupForm.get('startdate').errors|json}}{{submitted}}</pre>` to check what it's happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a getter in your .ts file:

```
get getControls() {
    return this.PopupForm.controls;
}
```

.html

```
<div *ngIf="getControls.startdate.errors && submitted">
    <div *ngIf="getControls.startdate.touched && getControls.startdate.errors?.required">
       Start Date is required *
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

did you try to do something like this ?

```
<div *ngIf="PopupForm.get('startdate')!.invalid && (PopupForm.get('startdate')!.dirty || PopupForm.get('startdate')!.touched)">
    <small class="form-text text-danger"
           *ngIf="PopupForm.get('startdate')?.errors?.required">
           This field is required.
    </small>
</div>
```